# How do I add my bot to a channel? The bot doesn't show up in search.

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Any suggestions? Is it an issue of an official Telegram client or something else?
[image: IFTTT bot doesn't show up in global search]

Comment: Just tried with my channel and your bot, is it this one? http://petradam.eu/iftt-bot.png

Comment: Yes. And I use Android. It seems that global search doesn't work properly on Android

Comment: Yes, I was trying on Windows app, and found the bot also in iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

You can add bot as channel admin: open channel info -> administrators -> add administartor -> search your bot.

Comment: Now that is the question: the bot does not show up in global search.

Comment: Try to find via "@bot_name_here"